# How to get the permissions from shared folder using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shared-directory

I want to get list of permissions from
folder> Properties> Sharing tab> Advanced Sharing> Permissions.
like a picture.

I looked through Googling few days but could not find it.

I found some code but it was for Security tab.

I need get the permissions list solution, not a set permissions solution.

[image: ------ Image for explain ------]

In this picture, I expect to get

> ["Everyone"]

If there are another account like "testAccount", "Administrator"
I expect to get

> ["Everyone", "testAccount", "Administrator"]

Please help me.
Thanks :)

```
        string path = @"C:\test";
        string NtAccountName = @"Domain\account";

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

        //Go through the rules returned from the DirectorySecurity
        foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rule.IdentityReference.Value);
        }
```

Comment: `I found some codes look like what I want. But I don't know how to use it.`  S.O. is not the ideal place to learn new concepts from scratch - I would recommend finding a tutorial

Comment: Hi John. Thanks to reply. I usually programming in JAVA, and I'm beginner in C#. I wrote I found some codes that look like what I want but it isn't work. If you know solutions or have a link for solve, please help me.